# How to dynamically create object properties, depending on some condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can one create or not create object properties that are dependent on some condition.  For example one can define a variable that's dependent on some condition by doing:

```js
const foo = someCondition ? true : undefined
```

However what I'd like to do is the following in pseudo code:

```js
const foo = {
  someCondition ? { a: true }
  b: 'b' 
}
// returning { a: true, b: 'b' } if someCondition or { b: 'b'} if not.
```

One way to solve this is via:

```js
const foo = { ...someCondition ? { a: true }: {}, ...{ b: 'b'} }
```

However this doesn't seems like a great solution to me as it requires the creation of a bunch of intermediate objects and then merging them into a new object - which won't be performant.

Another solution is:

```js
const foo = { b: 'b'}
if(someCondition) foo.a = true
```

Which is okayish, however it splits object creation into two or more distinct steps, which I also don't like.

And another solution:

```js
const foo = { b: 'b'}
if(someCondition) Object.defineProperty(foo,'a',{ value: true})
```

Similar to the solution above.

Perhaps one of you has found a better way to do this than I have?

Comment: *which won't be performant* - if you are not running million of these operations per second I wouldn't bother with optimizing the performance

Comment: Can't you just do this? `const foo = { a: someCondition ? true : undefined, b: 'b' }`

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle that will not work if you're using `in` or `hasOwnProperty()` though.

Comment: I personally like this for visibility. `const foo = { b: 'b'}; if (someCondition) foo.a = true`
You could also delete after: `if (!someCondition) delete foo.a;`

Comment: @Barry Michael Doyle - the problem with that is that it leaves irrelevant properties in my object prototypes, which will confuse me later on.

Comment: @Steven97102 it works with `in` and `hasOwnProperty` just fine https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzg9gtiAwjAdgEwJZg6iBeCMAJwFcQBuAWACgaBjVKSAMxhnwgG8IBDALmjwkqTNlwB+QqRAQBJdCGYYUINABoIAIwEByTTogBfKrWoZmEABQ6eB5RFYwAlBAYpYoAHTAYAc0sABjwQ9o4QAG4YwQA6AcqxAU4mNOZWjp4AFjxQAPIA7igACkQwAA4gRGAAnta2Ti5uHiDefoHBoWwRURCxWbkFxWUV1QlJQA

Comment: @AluanHaddad it doesn't work if the condition is false. The key is still visible even though the value is set to undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Using prototypes you could do it like so:

```
let myBool = true;

function Obj() {
    if (myBool) this.myConditionedProp = "5"
}

let myObj = new Obj()
```

You can also directly pass parameters in the prototype function:

```
function Obj(age) {
    this.name = 'John'
    if(age) this.age = age
}

let myObj = new Obj(15)

console.log(myObj.name, myObj.age)
```

This method have the merit not to split the object creation, despite not really providing more simplicity.

Comment: The merit of this approach is not splitting the object creation code - and so it is certainly, another tool to add to my toolbox.  Thanks for sharing!